# com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: SQL function not found. If you are attempting to call a java UDF, Java services are not enabled

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, sybase

Trying to fetch data with this method in my repo and put into object:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value="select new com.mycompany.entity.User(ID, NAME, SURNAME) FROM UTF.do.[USERSTB] WHERE EML_NO = :emlNumber", nativeQuery = true)
List<EmlInfoEntity> findByEMLNumber(@Param("emlNumber") Integer emlNumber);
```

And I get this error:

```
Caused by: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: SQL function not found. If you are attempting to call a java UDF, Java services are not enabled.

    at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.processEed(Tds.java:4117)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.nextResult(Tds.java:3207)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ResultGetter.nextResult(ResultGetter.java:78)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(SybStatement.java:291)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(SybStatement.java:273)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.queryLoop(SybStatement.java:2410)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.executeQuery(SybStatement.java:2396)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SybPreparedStatement.java:272)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy180.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
    ... 113 more
```

I need it to return the User object:

```
[
  {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "tommy",
   "surname": "lens"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Sybase [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/apbs02s01.html):

> **Enable JAVA services**
>
> *To use any java service like JMS, CMP, timers etc. configured with Sybase, java should be enabled on Sybase Adaptive Server.*

The command you should execute in the ***Sybase Adaptive Server*** is:

**`sp_configure "enable java",1`**

---

**[B.2.1. Special notes on Sybase](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/apbs02s01.html)**

Comment: Do i do this on terminal in my project? I doubt I have access to the config on the prod/dev server.

Comment: docs say that you must use Sybase Adaptive Server for doing so..

Comment: You have to run this in the Sybase database instance to enable the feature - you also need sa (i.e. DBA) admin access to enable it.